# How can I update everything installed through Homebrew after OSX upgrade?

Tags: macos, homebrew, package-management

After updating to 10.8 ‘Mountain Lion’ I’m wondering how I can rebuild everything I have installed through the packaging system Homebrew (similar to MacPorts) to ensure all dependencies are installed optimally for the new system. How can it easily be achieved? The help file offers no hints as to how I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 131):

Use the command `brew upgrade` in the terminal to update all of the packages.  As for rebuilding all of your programs for the new OS build, there is no reason to do this as the compiled binary should result as the same.  If you are noticing any issues, I would just uninstall and reinstall the packages that you are having issues with.

Comment: Seems like `brew cask upgrade` is also needed to get apps updated. (I run into https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/49716#issuecomment-413515303 when I did - the workaround fixed it though)

Comment: `brew upgrade --cask` is preferred now

Comment: @Xorifelse Why is `--cask` preferred?

Comment: @aryanm : Because `brew cask upgrade` doesn't work anymore (`Error: Unknown command: cask`).

Comment: `brew upgrade --cask` not updated my excited packages like _Flutter_. using `brew upgrade --g` will be preferred as mentioned in [Manpage](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage) : -**g**, **--greedy**: _Also include outdated casks with auto_updates true or version :latest._ **--greedy-latest**: _Also include outdated casks including those with version :latest._
**--greedy-auto-updates**: _Also include outdated casks including those with auto_updates true._